# How to apply reverb effect to audio files using commandline tools only?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm used to the reverb effect in Audacity, and was wondering if the same or at least, similar effect would be done using ffmpeg alone (or at least, commandline tools only).

Any ways to do this with commandline tools (like ffmpeg) only? (working example is appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one working example to use a convolution reverb with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -i "CUSTOM_museum hall.wav" -lavfi afir temp.mp3
```

I used one of the Lexicon impulse responses from [this page](https://resoundsound.com/4-impulse-response-reverb-packs/).

Answer (score 1):

- `ffmpeg` manual contains plenty of examples: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html
- You can use `sox` as well: http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

Comment: I'm well aware of those example...but it would be more helpful if you could post an actual working example to do what the post mention, with ffmpeg/sox :) (not diminishing your effort in answering, just my two cents from a OP perspective)

Comment: From the manual: *Apply reverb to stream using mono IR file as second input, complete command using ffmpeg:* `ffmpeg -i input.wav -i middle_tunnel_1way_mono.wav -lavfi afir output.wav` There are dozens of example on the Internet. Google for it.

Comment: yeah, works :) (feel free to update your post with this if you want)

Comment: where do you get the IR file?

Comment: exactly what I tried to know myself, still not sure what it is either @ColinD